# Is Unity's WorldAnchorStore a single collection?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am trying to figure out what is happening in an application I an writing where world anchors are being shared across a service to two clients.  My Unity App has two manager classes that have a private member which references unity's WorldAnchorStore.

If I call WorldAnchorStore.GetAsync(callback that assigns anchorStore private member to be used in this class) in Class A, and have a similar call in class B, does the same collection of world anchors get returned?  Also would class A and B potentially have two separate world anchor stores that could get out of sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WorldAnchorStore is unique to the application. Class A and class B will receive a reference to the same WorldAnchorStore instance.